# Angular UI router `reloadOnSearch:false` with stateParams

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I got `reloadOnSearch:false` working with query params but is there an equivalent for `stateParams`?

When I do `state.go` with new state params, state is reloaded.

Here is my config -

```
$stateProvider
  .state('app', {
    url: '/:appId',
    templateUrl: '../views/app.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl',
    reloadOnSearch: false
  })
  .state('/app.items', {
    url: '/items',
    templateUrl: '../views/items.html',
    controller: 'ItemsCtrl'
  })
  .state('app.upload', {
    url: '/upload',
    templateUrl: '../views/upload.html',
    controller: 'UploadCtrl'
  })
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
}])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `{notify: false}` in your `$state.go`.
For example:

```
$state.go('app', { /*your new parameters*/}, {notify: false});
```

This way the page won't be reloaded.

Comment: That doesn't work. Also, `{notify: false}` is deprecated and they recommend to use `reloadOnSearch: false` now

Comment: Well reloadOnSearch seems to be deprecated too : https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/state.statedeclaration.html#reloadonsearch. I learned something today. ;-)